# How to select porduct details using id in MongoDB on Nodejs with Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
products_router.get("/productDetails/:id", function (req,res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    mongoose.model('products').find({}, function(err,products){
        res.render('productDetails', {
            "detailObj":products
         });
    });
});
```

Using 'req.params.id' i got the id of that product. how can i get the products displayed in the other page

Comment: I'm not too sure what are you asking? Did you want to render `req.params.id`?

Comment: `mongoose.model('products').findOne({"_id":id}, function(err,products)...` should work.

Comment: i am a beginner for node... please can you give me an example that how can i get the product. Just for example i have field name 'itme' how can i display inside the function which u suggested. just a console.log will do... Can you? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just add the condition with `id` in the find function: `mongoose.model('products').find({"_id":id}, function(err,products){
        res.render('productDetails', {
            "detailObj":products
         });
    });`